# entr: recognition of new files recursively

Tags: linux, find, ls

To keep track of newly added files in a directory (and it's subdirs) I want to use `entr`

```
ls -d /tmp/*  | entr -p notify-send "new file added."
```

But when I add new files to `/tmp/` or `/tmp/foo/` nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular use case for using `entr` ? It is generally strongly discouraged to parse `ls`:
[Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead)

I think in your case you would be better off using `incrond`:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/trigger-commands-on-file-or-directory-changes-with-incron/
(IN_CREATE would be of particular interest to your situation)

To my knowledge `incrond` is not able to watch subdirectories, so if you need to also watch all subdirectories of /tmp, maybe `watcher` is more suited to your situation:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088179/watch-a-subdirectory-with-incron

Word of caution, without knowing your special use case:
/tmp is used by all kinds of processes. It may not be very wise/practical to try and track all of its changes.

Comment: I want to get notified about incoming email (offlineimap). `ls` is not a must, but entr seems to be easier to setup on screen notifications

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
ls -d /tmp/* | entr -p echo "New File"
```

on one pane.Then on another pane type

```
echo "hello" > /tmp/test123456.txt
```

Notice that 'New File' is echoed on the first pane

Answer (score 0):

I am using this to update an html version of a markdown text:

```
# Preview a comment written in Markdown
cpv() {
    echo ">INFO> Refreshing preview"
    find | entr -d generate_comment_preview.sh
}
cpvr() {
    cpv
    if [[ $? > 0 ]]; then
        echo ">INFO> Launching cpvr again"
        cpvr
    fi
}
```

Then I open the file with Epiphany (gnome-web) and it refreshes automagically.